# Programmed Slider Constraint is Not Updating

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, uislider

I have am attempting to learn how to populate a view in my storyboard with sliders and buttons, programmatically.  I am trying, currently, to get one programmed slider to adhere to a programmed `NSLayoutConstraint`

Here is my code:

```
let centerXConstraint =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.volumeSliderP, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10.0)

self.view.addConstraint(centerXConstraint)
```

I should mention, that when I substitute the first `item` for a slider which already exists on the view (which was placed via Storyboard, with it's own constraints also placed with IB/Storyboard), it does updated correctly with the above `NSLayoutConstraint` code.  Also, I have been able to update my programmed `volumeSliderP` with custom code to change it's handle and rotate it to vertical successfully.

What step am I missing to allow this `NSLayoutConstraint` code to work upon my programmed slider?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: can you show the complete code of creating your slider and adding constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with constraints in code, you need to do two (maybe three) things, regardless of control type:

- Set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false.

Failure to do so will set off constraint conflicts, which will appear in the console log. I usually create an extension to UIView for this:

```
public func turnOffAutoResizing() {
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    for view in self.subviews as [UIView] {
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
}
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` (after adding my subviews) I simply add a line:

```
view.turnOffAutoResizing()
```

- Consider if any subviews have [intrinsic content size](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html).

As explained in the linked Apple doc, if you have label and a text field, the text field will expand to fit the label without the need for setting widths. *A UISlider does not have an intrinsic width but it does have an intrinsic height.*

- So in your case you need to not only set position, it needs to define the width.

A combination of `top` and `leading` will yield enough for the layout engine to know "where" and "height", but not "width". Same would go if you defined "centerX" and something - you didn't list any code - for the Y factor (top, bottom, centerY).

If I'm stating this clearly, you should be able to see that the engine will know enough to say (in frame coordinates) "start the slider at X/Y, height is XX points (it has intrinsic height), but how long should it be?"

I typically set either top, leading, and trailing... or top, centerX, and width. But it varies with the need.

Comment: Excellent answer!  Thank you!  (for the record, I'm applying an "equal width to superview * mult" & centerX so the same location will work on different size iPad screens)